# Passing functions and member functions as an argument to another function

Tags: c++

I've written a library that allows one to bind functions to a key event by checking the received ASCII characters. It works perfectly for non-member functions defined in the main code. It doesn't work for member functions. I'm aware that this is because member functions and non-member functions are of a different type. How can I pass a function of a previously undefined class to this function in my library?

The type is defined:

```
typedef void (*tobind)();
```

The function in question:

```
void Keybinder::bind(char key,int mode,tobind func) {
switch(mode){
    //execute depending on the event mode argument
    case 0:
        pressed[key] = func; //assign the function to the character pressed event
        break;
    case 1:
        down[key] = func; //assing the function to the character down event
        break;
    case 2:
        released[key] = func; //assign the function to the character released event
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: maybe std::function? C and C++ declaration syntax can be nasty, std::function helps with this and other things.

Comment: It goes somewhat further than _"because member functions and non-member functions are of a different type."_ Those types live within entirely different "classes" of types.

Comment: Google for "member function bind C++".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a compiler that supports C++11 syntax then I would suggest using the [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) and [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) methods.

Your typedef would look like this:

```
typedef std::function<void()> tobind;
```

You would use std::bind like so:

```
auto func = std::bind(&Foo, arg1, arg2); // non-member usage
auto memFunc = std::bind(&A::MemberFoo, aInstance, arg1, arg2); // member-function usage
```

Answer (score 0):

use *forward decleration* + `std::bind`:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
    void Keybinder::bind(char key,int mode,F&& f,Args&&... args){
    std::function<void()> callback = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f),std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //use callback as original func
 }
```

do notice, that *non static member functions* need `this` pointer being passed them.

```
struct Foo{
  void func(){};
};

Foo f;
keybinder.bind('a',4,&Foo::func,&f);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass a function of a previously undefined class to this function in my library?

You cannot do that with the existing interface of `Keybinder::bind`.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, a somewhat ugly intermediate solution - if your library's binding method allows it - is to bind to a `static` `class` function, and pass the specific instance as a reference/pointer (in whatever 'user data' your library allows to callbacks). The `static` function is able to act as a `friend` of referenced instances and hence access their members, almost as if they were its own.

However, you're basically going back to ye olde C-style 'OOP', so this is not a very elegant way to do it, if you have neater alternatives available.

I'm going to assume that at the time I used this pattern, the library I was using didn't support any nicer way. B-)